# How to change the firmware of my NETGEAR WGT624 v2 to DD-WRT

Tags: router, dd-wrt, firmware

In reference to [my previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/121657/soho-netgear-wireless-router-disconnects-when-downloading-torrents): I can't find the appropriate firmware for my NETGEAR WGT624 v2 router. I went on the dd-wrt web site and I read the wiki, but I didn't see any files or instructions on how to change the firmware.

The [router database](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database) lists my router, but as I said: no files. In addition the "Supported" column lists "wip", what is wip?

```
Router Database
4 routers found
Manufacturer    Model   Revision    Supported   Activation required
Netgear         WGT624      v1          wip         no
Netgear         WGT624      v2          wip         no
...
```

The only thing listed for my router on the dd-wrt web site is:

```
Router details     
Chipset: AR2312A      
RAM: 16 MB  
FLASH: 4 MB     

Additional information
    * OpenWRT Wiki: Netgear WGT624
    * Unbrick procedure
```

Is the router supported? Can I change the firmware? If yes, then how can I change it?

Comment: WIP = Work In Progress.  Basically, it's not supported, but they're working on it.

Comment: @hyperslug I would post that as an answer.

Comment: @hyperslug - and I would upvote you too...

Comment: lol, the pressure...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like DD-WRT works for this model.

As stated in the above comment:

> WIP = Work In Progress. Basically, it's not supported, but they're working on it

Digging deeper, it looks like work on it has slowed/halted, judging by the 2 year old thread on their forum: http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=33975.

DD-WRT just links you to the [OpenWRT WGT624 site](http://wiki.openwrt.org/oldwiki/openwrtdocs/hardware/netgear/wgt624) where some fellow has done some experimentation with his, perhaps soldering on a JTAG port.

I'm afraid you're stuck with the stock firmware.

Comment: Then it looks like I might be shopping for a new router :).